# What search engine does mongodb use?

Tags: mongodb, search-engine

I see searching on [mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/dosearchsite.action?queryString=api&where=DOCS) is lightning fast. The search results are within 1 second. From what I know, mongodb doesnot support full text search. However, that does not seem to be the case while using their search. Not only do the results are fast, the site also gives additional hint when you mistype search text (like how google does).

I am very much interested on how to achieve these results? What combination of search engine/hardware are they using?

Thanks.

Comment: The page you linked to looks like an Atlassian Confluence search results page.  I wouldn't be surprised if MongoDB isn't part of the stack used to serve their public website at all.

Comment: What should this pointless comment? MongoDB.org uses Confluence. Point. MongoDB has no fulltext search and MongoDB is not a CMS. Point

Comment: Thanks, just learned mongodb.org does not use mongodb database in the backend. Bit disappointed though. As many of you said, mongodb.org is using search engine from the proprietary Confluence CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That search is part of Confluence by Atlassian. As far as I know it's not using mongodb for the search backend, as it's not supported by Confluence. No idea about the hardware behind it...

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Supported+Platforms

Answer (score 0):

This question does not belong here.
You can clearly check yourself on the search page that the site is driven by Confluence.

Comment: Could you please guide me where to put this question? I could not find the right place to ask a general question. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to question? The question has been answered twice.